# wait for loop to complete before checking if any child div exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am trying to wait for my firebase for each loop to complete and once it completes, I want to check how many divs were populated in my parent `div`. If `length == 0`, that means the result from the firebase query came back empty and nothing was added.

However, the conditional gets hit every time, regardless of if there were `0` results appended to my `div` or many. It looks like the .then doesn't actually wait for my for each loop to complete and inject the html. It runs immediately and thats why the if conditional always gets hit. Help please...

```js
firebase.database().ref('zones').once('value', (snapper) => {
  snapper.forEach((snap) => {
    //for each data point in firebase, inject it into the html
    })
  }).then(() => {
      //once the loop is done and the html has been populated, do a check to see if any divs were created with the queried data
      //if divs length is 0, that means the result came back empty
      if($("#parent > div").length == 0) { console.log("no results") }
  });
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML file, as well as the code inside your forEach loop?

Comment: Adding elements to the DOM is asynchronous. You could try moving the whole process out of the Firebase function. When the data comes in trigger a new promise or callback function that does the task you need, separately. The .then() refers to the completion of the Firebase call rather than the completion of the forEach.